# How can I continuously show the volume icon when volume is increased/decreased as Youtube video player does

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

So I am trying to clone Youtube's video player where when volume gets increased/decreased it shows a volume icon that shows in the center as in this image:
[The feedback am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbJUj.png)

I've managed to do that, but the feedback only shows when the state changes (i.e: Muted, High and Low) as shown here:
[The clone i've made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWaQ3.gif).

and instead shows continuously every time I press arrow up/down like youtube does.

JS:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
 switch (e.code) {
    case "ArrowUp":
      volume(+0.05);
      break;
    case "ArrowDown":
      volume(-0.05);
      break;
  }
});

function volume(change) {
  video.volume = Math.min(1, Math.max(0, video.volume + change));
  volumeSlider.value = video.volume;
 if (video.muted || video.volume === 0) {
volumeHigh.classList.remove("animate-feedback");
volumeLow.classList.remove("animate-feedback");
volumeMuted.classList.add("animate-feedback");
} else if (video.volume >= 0.5) {
volumeHigh.classList.add("animate-feedback");
volumeLow.classList.remove("animate-feedback");
volumeMuted.classList.remove("animate-feedback");
} else {
volumeHigh.classList.remove("animate-feedback");
volumeLow.classList.add("animate-feedback");
volumeMuted.classList.remove("animate-feedback");
  } 
}
```

*Any suggested edits to this question to make it better and more clear would be appreciated*

Things I tried?

actually there is nothing i've thinked of to do till now unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

It's a little complex thing, but here's the idea that you should implement with JS and CSS if necessary.

At the HTML page level, add a seekbar

```
<div class='seek'>
      <div class='seek-bar'>

      </div>
</div>
```

that you will personalize with CSS, or add a range type input

```
<video id="media">
    <source src="your_path.mp4">
</video>
<input type="range" min='0' max='1' step='0.1' id="for-js" onchange="updateVolume('media')"> // We will consider this line because it is simpler
```

select your seekbar with JS to be able to update it according to the value captured in the range type input.

```
function updateVolume(id_media){
     let media = document.getElementById(id_media);
     let seek = document.getElementById('for-js');
     media.volume = seek.value;
}
```

you can call this function on all the pages you want.

This works, please note that I do not take into account the effects you want.

Comment: Looks like you're answering the wrong question :)